# Temps quotidiens à l'oral en français

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

J'étudie français par moi-même et j'ai appris quelques temps verbaux en utilisent de ressources sur l'Internet, néanmoins il n'y a pas longtemps que je réalisé que j'ai appris quelques choses que ne sont pas présentes au quotidien, par exemple j'ai utilisé le passé simple pour certaines phrases où j'ai dû utiliser le passé composé (a cause de ma langue maternelle qu'est l'espagnol où le passé simple est quotidien)

Ma question est, Que temps verbaux sont les plus utilisé ou quotidiens à l'oral?

Je sais que le suivant temps verbaux existent en français.

```
Indicatif (présent, passé composé, imparfait, plus-que-parfait, passé simple, passé antérieur, futur simple, futur antérieur)

Subjonctif (présent, passé, imparfait, plus-que-parfait)

Conditional (présent, passé première et seconde forme)

Imperative et participe (présent, passé)
```

Je ne veux pas apprendre tous ces temps tout de suite, je seulement veux les savoir, selon mon apprentissage et à mesure que j'améliore mon niveau (je crois que je suis entre les niveaux A1 et A2), je sais quels  temps les plus quotidiens je dois apprendre et j'évite étudier auxquels que ne sont pas  utilisés à l'oral.

Pardonnez-moi si j'ai fait des erreurs de grammaire en écrivant ma question.

Comment: _qui_ est espangol et _quel_ temps verbaux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les temps les plus utilisés sont l'indicatif présent, le futur simple, l'imparfait et le passé composé.

Le passé simple et le passé antérieur ne sont pas utilisés à l'oral.

Le conditionnel passé seconde forme a presque disparu.

Les autres temps sont moins utilisés, mais obligatoires dans certains cas (par exemple, l'impératif présent sert à donner un ordre). Les cas où le subjonctif imparfait et plus-que-parfait doivent être utilisés sont toutefois tellement rares qu'ils ont également pratiquement disparu de l'usage courant.

Comment: Je pense que les temps suivants sont quand même très courants :

- Indicatif plus-que-parfait ('j'avais bien aimé ce film à l'époque')

- Conditionnel présent ('j'aimerais bien aller au cinéma demain')

- Conditionnel passé ('j'aurais bien aimé aller au cinéma hier')

Comment: j'ai remplacé mon "peu" par "moins" pour la nuance. Je ne voulais pas dire que les autres temps n'étaient pas utilisés, mais s'il faut commencer par quelques temps je pense que ma première liste peut suffire. Par exemple, tout le monde vous comprendrais si vous disiez "j'ai bien aimé ce film". Par contre, je suis d'accord avec vous que le conditionnel présent est nécessaire et relativement fréquent (le conditionnel passé l'est par contre moins que le subjonctif présent, par exemple, pour peu que vous soyez un adepte de la subordination).

Comment: Bref, il est difficile de mettre une limite à une liste car tous les temps ont leur raison d'être (sauf le conditionnel passé seconde forme qui peut se remplacer par le conditionnel passé première forme sans perte de sens). Présent, imparfait et futur de l'indicatif sont les premier temps que l'on apprend à l'école et ce n'est pas uniquement parce qu'ils servent de base à de nombreux autres temps.